# NOTICE Undefined index: file while using isset and array_key_exists()

Tags: php, codeigniter, notice

I have met this Notice while programming php with CodeIgniter
code like this.Its used for showing line and filename while logging.
I tried this

```
    //get debug messages such as functionname, linenum,etc.
    if ($level == 'debug') {
        $debug_info = debug_backtrace(!DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT
                                && DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS);
        $debug_info = $debug_info[1];
        $debug_message = '('.
            isset($debug_info['file'])?$debug_info['file']:''.
            isset($debug_info['class'])?$debug_info['class']:''.
            isset($debug_info['type'])?$debug_info['type']:''.
            isset($debug_info['function'])?$debug_info['function']:''.
            isset($debug_info['line'])?$debug_info['line']:''.
            ')';
        $message = $debug_message.$message;
    }
```

and use array_key_exist() to make the judge ,but it still cause NOTICE like this

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: file
>
> Filename: core/Common.php
>
> Line Number: 364

Many thanks for answering the question

here is the dumped data

```
array(4) {
  ["function"]=>
  string(5) "index"
  ["class"]=>
  string(7) "Welcome"
  ["type"]=>
  string(2) "->"
  ["args"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume `isset($debug_info['file'])?$debug_info['file']:''.` is line 364? Could you try to var_dump `$debug_info` and add this to your question.

Comment: Try $debug_info['file']?$debug_info['file']:''. I assume the file key will always be set even if there is no value?

Comment: This function was called many times the whole dumped data is too long;I added the most recent dump message

Comment: Can you add an exceptionhandling to the code to only dump `$debug_info` when the error orrurs? PHP.net: [Try and Catch](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: @deceze Many thanks....I made such a low level mistake.I thought PHP operators work like C

Comment: @DKSan Thanks for taking time to help me ,@deceze got the real reason.still thanks

Answer (score 2):

`'(' . isset(...)` will always evaluate to `true`, hence `$debug_info['file']` will always be evaluated whether it's *set* or not. The problem is the way you're chaining the conditions and operations. You need to delimit and group them explicitly, otherwise it doesn't do what you think it does.

```
'(' . (isset(..) ? 'foo' : 'bar') . ( .. ? .. : .. ) . ...
```